# Grep/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to find and replace every occurrence of

httpaccess

with

httpaccessabc

in every file of name "access.html" in a particular folder

Comment: The title of your question suggests that you want to do a recursive search for files, whereas the contents of your question and the answer you've accepted suggest that there's only a single file. You should [edit] your question so the two things match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the folder for access.html then :-

```
sed -i.bak 's/httpaccess/httpaccesabc/g' access.html
```

(or)

```
sed -i.bak 's/httpaccess/&abc/g' access.html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i.bak 's/httpaccess/&abc/g' **/access.html
```

- Use `globstar` with `**` to match your filename, recursively.
- Use `sed -i` to perform an in-place substitution.

This will create backup files with a suffix `.bak`. To unset the shell option, use `shopt -u globstar` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`find` is your friend

```
 find . -type f -name 'access.html' \
 -exec sed -i.bak 's/httpaccess/&abc/g' {} \;
```

**Edit**

To replace whole pattern use :

```
 find . -type f -name 'access.html' \
 -exec sed -i.bak 's/abcde/wazsde/g' {} \;
```

---

**Notes**

1. Replace `.` with `/your/path` of concern.
2. The `\` at the end of first line is just to split the command into two lines for more readability.
3. The `g` option with sed `s` command is for global substitution.

Comment: what if i need to replace whole text ,i mean if i need to replace "abcde" with "wazsde" in access.html file

Comment: @rreddy use `s/abcde/wazsde/` for one substitution and  `s/abcde/wazsde/g` for global replace.

Comment: thanks @sjsam it worked for me ..but it is creating a .bak file as well ..is there a way to do it without creating it or removing it right after it created that file

Comment: @rreddy : `-i` option with sed is for inplace editing. If you remove `.bak` file after `-i` it wont create a backup file.